# Infrequent syntax error thrown by YouTube's iframe API in production. How could this be occurring?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I log client-side errors thrown by my application and have been seeing the following error occurring infrequently, but consistently, in a production environment. I'm assuming it's not a fluke or a PC in a bad state, but I am unable to reproduce it locally.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

It is being thrown by YouTube's iframe API located here: https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api. That is, the Error objects URL specifically indicates that it is this source and not www-widgetapi.

This error is confusing me because the token `<` is only referenced once, inside a for loop, and it's perfectly valid syntax.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be occurring?

I simply inject the script using jQuery:

```
if (this.get('inserted')) {
    Backbone.Wreqr.radio.channel('error').commands.trigger('log:message', 'API script already inserted');
    return;
}

//  This function will be called when the API is fully loaded. Needs to be exposed globally so YouTube can call it.
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = this._onYouTubeIframeAPIReady.bind(this);

$('<script>', {
    src: 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api',
}).insertBefore($('script:first'));

this.set('inserted', true);
```

Here's the beautified version of their script:

```
if (!window['YT']) {
    var YT = {
        loading: 0,
        loaded: 0
    };
}
if (!window['YTConfig']) {
    var YTConfig = {
        'host': 'http://www.youtube.com'
    };
}
if (!YT.loading) {
    YT.loading = 1;
    (function() {
        var l = [];
        YT.ready = function(f) {
            if (YT.loaded) {
                f();
            } else {
                l.push(f);
            }
        };
        window.onYTReady = function() {
            YT.loaded = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
                try {
                    l[i]();
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        };
        YT.setConfig = function(c) {
            for (var k in c) {
                if (c.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                    YTConfig[k] = c[k];
                }
            }
        };
        var a = document.createElement('script');
        a.id = 'www-widgetapi-script';
        a.src = 'https:' + '//s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflBfDu58/www-widgetapi.js';
        a.async = true;
        var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
    })();
}
```

Comment: I often see that when some JSON is requested, and the page errors with some HTML and `JSON.parse()` is fed some HTML. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Hmmmm. Potentially? However all I am doing is inserting a <script> element with the src pointing to iframe_api. Maybe something is going on behind the scenes, but the stacktrace for the error says it's coming from iframe_api (on line 1, but that's not helpful)

Comment: If you look at requests made from that code, are any being returned error pages or similar?